# Enable CORS on subdirectories under /var/www on Apache

Tags: apache, cors

I'm trying to enable CORS for a subdirectory on my site, after reading that using a wildcard for domain on the root folder can be a security risk.

This is part of my apache2.conf, the unsafe wildcard on root folder.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
     <IfModule mod_headers.c>
             Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
     </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Is there a way I can get CORS enabled only for a subdirectory of var/www?

I need to remove the

```
'Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"'
```

from var/www, but when I try to do:

```
<Directory /var/www/subdir/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
     <IfModule mod_headers.c>
             Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
     </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

I get an error in Chrome telling me

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Is there a way to get the CORS enabled for subfolder and not for root?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am replying almost a year since you asked, but I wanted to do the same thing as you.  My only issue was that I was targeting the wrong directory (forgot to put /var/www/**html**/subdir).  When I targeted the correct directory, I could enable CORS on only that specific directory.

I did not specify any directives for that directory other than that.  Here is how my apache2.conf looks like:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options +FollowSymLinks -Includes -Indexes
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        <LimitExcept GET POST HEAD>
                deny from all
        </LimitExcept>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/subdir/>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: I gave up on it, and will try again with your changes and accept the answer later. I might have forgotten the html subdirectory..

Comment: nice solution, I don't prefer shortcuts like using the .htaccee file